# Background elimination of an image in python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to eliminate the background from an image. Below is image attachment :

[snacks with white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGtYs.jpg) and make the background black for further analysis on the resulting image.

Kindly help me with the elimination, the background could be of any colour but will be uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task is part of the field of [image segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation). It can be done in many ways.
You can use [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/).

[Here](https://www.codepasta.com/computer-vision/2016/11/06/background-segmentation-removal-with-opencv.html) is a tutorial for background removal in openCV.